# How can I put each element of this array into a string?

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to search an array for check boxes that have been checked. Then I need to take the checked boxes that are selected and put them into a string to show the user what they have selected(maybe into a Dialog popup box). I don't know what syntax to use for this or method to do this after a lot of trial and error I have come here.

Check boxes:

```
JCheckBox s1 = new JCheckBox("Mowing",false);
    JCheckBox s2 = new JCheckBox("Edging",false);
    JCheckBox s3 = new JCheckBox("Trimming",false);
    JCheckBox s4 = new JCheckBox("Blowing",false);
    JCheckBox s5 = new JCheckBox("Mulch",false);
    JCheckBox s6 = new JCheckBox("Hedges",false);
    JCheckBox s7 = new JCheckBox("Pruning Trees", false);
    JCheckBox s8 = new JCheckBox("Landscaping",false);
    JCheckBox s9 = new JCheckBox("Weeding", false);
    JCheckBox s10 = new JCheckBox("Leaf Removal", false);
```

Array and for loop with an if statement to check for checked boxes

```
JCheckBox[] boxes = {s1,s2,s3,s4,s5,s6,s7,s8,s9,s10};
        int count = 0;
        int i;
        //String for checked boxes to be put into
        String requested = " ";
        for(i = 0; i < boxes.length; ++i)
        {
            if(boxes[i].isSelected())
            {
                requested = boxes[i].getText();
                ++count;
                //Add the checked boxes to a string. This is where I am stuck
            }
        }
```

Comment: [StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html)

Comment: So I would create a StringBuilder object and append the requested variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe just do

```
requested += boxes[i].getText() + " ";
```

Or using StringBuilder:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (i = 0; i < boxes.length; ++i) {
    ...
    sb.append(boxes[i].getText() + " ");
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `JOptionPane` for your popup window. Hope this can help you!

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"requested ="+ requested);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's relatively easy in java 8:

```
String delimiter = " ";
String s = Arrays.stream(boxes)
                 .filter((b) -> b.isSelected()) // restrict to selected
                 .map((b)->b.getText()) // get text for each element
                 .collect(Collectors.joining(delimiter)); // join the strings
```